# Android - Scheduling an Events to Occur Every 10ms?

Tags: android, performance, audio, timer, timedelay

I'm working on creating an app that allows very low bandwidth communication via high frequency sound waves. I've gotten to the point where I can create a frequency and do the fourier transform (with the help of Moonblink's open source code for [Audalyzer](http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Audalyzer)).

But here's my problem: I'm unable to get the code to run with the correct timing. Let's say I want a piece of code to execute every 10ms, how would I go about doing this?

I've tried using a TimerTask, but there is a huge delay before the code actually executes, like up to 100ms.

I also tried this method simply by pinging the current time and executing only when that time has elapsed. But there is still a delay problem. Do you guys have any ideas?

```
Thread analysis = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);

        long executeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        manualAnalyzer.measureStart();
        while (FFTransforming) 
        {          
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= executeTime)
            {
                //Reset the timer to execute again in 10ms
                executeTime+=10;

                //Perform Fourier Transform
                manualAnalyzer.doUpdate(0);

                //TODO: Analyze the results of the transform here...

            }
        }
        manualAnalyzer.measureStop();
    }
});
analysis.start();
```

Comment: have you tried putting executeTime=System.currentTimeMillis()+10; after doUpdate()? This way you should a an exact delay of 10 ms between doUpdates

Comment: I tried that at first, however, since current time is sometimes higher than execute time (due to garbage collection and other threads running) it fails to occur in exact 10 ms increments. And since I'm trying to sync with another device which is expecting these exact increments, it doesn't work entirely.

Comment: if you have control over all your code you might also try to eliminate the garbage collection by using allocation tracker and pre allocating all your objects. also note that if you get a spike in doUpdate which is longer than 10ms you timing will be off.

Comment: What do you mean control over all my code? Does the phone need to be rooted to do so? If not, I would be very willing to manage my own memory.

Comment: no i mean that you have access to all sources. If the memory allocations are done inside a closed source library you wouldn't be able to eliminate those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread/loop strategy is probably roughly as close as you're going to get. However, 10ms is not a lot of time, most Android devices are not super-powerful, and a Fourier transform is a lot of work to do. I find it unlikely that you'll be able to fit that much work in 10ms. I suspect you're going to have to increase that period.

Comment: I've timed it, and the fourier transform usually happens under 1 mS (normally around 300 uS). However, garbage collection and other threads running, the timing can sometimes be thrown off. I know I could set the thread priority to have the highest priority (-20 according to the documentation) but for some reason I feel like this is bad practice. What do you think?

Comment: Interesting, I'm a little surprised you can get it that fast but if it works it works. If it's really important that you be able to get 10ms increments, I wouldn't think it's bad to give the thread highest priority. Can you usually get 10ms intervals but occasionally get spikes?

Comment: Honestly, it seems to be working. But then again, I'm running it on a Galaxy Nexus  so it has a bit of an advantage over older phones, which is not good. And yeah, I get the occasional spike. Renard mentioned eliminating garbage collection, which would probably mitigate that issue. Do you know of another method? Or is there way to harshly enforce the TimerTask?

Comment: Eliminating or at least reducing GC is rather important if you want that consistent of performance. Be careful not to create new objects while that loop is active. A TimerTask isn't going to help you. It's not designed to be that accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a very different approach: Do not try to run *your* code in real time.

Instead, rely on only the low-level audio code running in real time, by recording (or playing) continuously for a period of time encompassing the events of interest.

Your code then runs somewhat asynchronously to this, decoupled by the audio buffers.  Your code's sense of time is determined not by the system clock as it executes, but rather by the defined inter-sample-interval of the audio data you work with. (ie, if you are using 48 Ksps then 10 mS later is 480 samples later)

You may need to modify your protocol governing interaction between the devices to widen the time window in which transmissions can be expected to occur.  Ie, you can have precise timing with respect to the actual modulation and symbols within a "packet", but you should not expect nearly the same order of precision in determining when a packet is sent or received - you will have to "find" it amidst a longer recording containing noise.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I can't figure out how I would synchronize the phones together. Because I'm using a an audio stream since I'm going to be loading the data dynamically dependent on what data is to be sent. Then playing it when it's ready. And I don't think there's a way to tell when the audio buffer is empty. Also, even if I could get some sort of call back function to execute after every sample is played, it wouldn't necessarily be called the instant it completes, it would be called as soon as the scheduler decides wouldn't it?

Comment: And even if it did, wouldn't it take some unknown amount of time to load the buffer again and begin playing it?

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You'll need to look into how to get lowest latency audio, yes.  More importantly, you'll need to design the protocol for longer turn-around windows between transmit and expectation of an acknowledgement.  You could well end up recording continuously, as the phone is probably fast enough to process the data looking for signals, it just can't reliably do it at exactly the right time.  Have some buffers in there buys you tolerance - the data gets recorded or created with exact timing, but the processing can happen a little early or late as long as the average keeps up.

Answer (score 1):

i changed your code so that it takes the execution time of doUpdate into account. The use of System.nanoTime() should also increase accuracy.

```
    public void run() {
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);

long executeTime=0;        
long nextTime = System.nanoTime();

manualAnalyzer.measureStart();
while (FFTransforming) 
{          
    if(System.nanoTime() >= nextTime)
    {
        executeTime = System.nanoTime();
        //Perform Fourier Transform
        manualAnalyzer.doUpdate(0);
        //TODO: Analyze the results of the transform here...
        executeTime = System.nanoTime() - executeTime;
        //guard against the case that doUpdate took longer than 10ms
        final long i = executeTime/10000000;
        //set the timer to execute again at the next full 10ms intervall
        nextTime+= 10000000+ i*10000000 
    }
}
manualAnalyzer.measureStop();
    }
```

**What else could you do?**

- eliminate Garbage Collection
- go native with the NDK (just an idea, this might as well give no benefit)

Comment: This is a good idea. It would be problematic if I missed a cycle though, the rest of the data would be corrupt. But, at least with this method, I can detect that.

Comment: (accidentally posted too soon)
And like you said above, the only way to eliminate garbage collection is avoid allocation. Would be be a good idea to call System.gc() when I know I have time to do so? That way, I doesn't occur as frequently. Or will ir still happen just as often?

Comment: There is no way to tell. I've seen this practice before but if you do lots of allocation during frametime gc's will happen eventually. Also i think that [Chris Strattons](http://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton) answer would be best solution to your problems :-)